# PHP file upload using HTTP header

Tags: php, http, file-upload, http-headers

I have the following PHP code-

```
    <?php

$uploaddir = getcwd().'/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>
```

What I want to do is, upload a text file by sending HTTP header to the script. This is the header I'm sending-

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------556304871068
```

POST content-

```
-----------------------------556304871068\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"\r\n
\r\n
512000\r\n
-----------------------------556304871068\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="example.txt"\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
\r\n
ThisText\r\n
\r\n
-----------------------------556304871068--\r\n
```

But it's returning an error message in response-

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  userfile in <b>C:\HostingSpaces\Test\mysite.com\wwwroot\admin\upload.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
<pre><br />
```

I can not understand why this error is appearing and how to solve this.

Note: The PHP script is working well when I'm uploading file normally (using an HTML upload page).

Edit: The HTML form code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where's the form html ?

Comment: If I got it right, you can upload the file using the html form but not when trying to use "header", how are you sending the headers to the script ? curl ?

Comment: No. I'm sending it through "Send HTTP Tool". And I can confirm it is sending the header.

Answer (score 0):

Check for `isset($_FILES['userfile'])` in the very first line of your code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile'])) {
....
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
...
} 

//end of your file or

} else {
echo 'There is no file to send!';
}
//end of your file
```

Comment: After adding these lines and sending the header it's showing "There is no file to send!" :\ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `print_r($_FILES);` when echo

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script to send a file with php/cURL via POST:

```
<?php
    $target_url = 'http://127.0.0.1/accept.php';
        //This needs to be the full path to the file you want to send.
    $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('./sample.jpeg');
        /* curl will accept an array here too.
         * Many examples I found showed a url-encoded string instead.
         * Take note that the 'key' in the array will be the key that shows up in the
         * $_FILES array of the accept script. and the at sign '@' is required before the
         * file name.
         */
    $post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);

        $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
?>
```

And here is the corresponding script to accept the file.

```
<?php
$uploaddir = realpath('./') . '/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file_contents']['name']);
echo '<pre>';
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_contents']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
    }
    echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "\n<hr />\n";
    print_r($_POST);
print "</pr" . "e>\n";
?>
```

Comment: The sample program you demonstrated above is sending the file using curl. But I need to do this by sending an HTTP header from client side. And I guess I'm doing something wrong with "$_FILES['userfile']" part.